# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '_Default.RadioButtonList2'

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a gridview which I bind with data from a database using a stored procedure.

Below is part of the code behind where I get the error above:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetList(int pageIndex){
 ....
 .....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerGroup", RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue); //Error here
....
....
 }
```

I have this code for the gridview:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" 
                      Font-Size="1em" EnableViewState="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Africa</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" >America</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Europe</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Asia/asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Australia</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How do I get the value of the radio button selected and pass it to the stored procedures?
When I remove the line code everything is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you have created webmethod, which can not access any server controls.
Remove it.

If it is required, then pass RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue in that function from client side.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetList(int pageIndex,string radiovalue){
 ....
 .....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerGroup", radiovalue); 
....
....
 }
```

hope it works.